# pgfgantt: Is it possible to create bars with "double" labels?

Tags: pgfgantt

here's a problem I have: I want my gantt bars to have two types of labels --  one on the side of the chart, and one inline -- and I'm having a hard time making it work. The code I use to generate the chart is listed below:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid,
x unit=1cm,
title height=1]{12}{12}
  \gantttitle{Quarters}{12} \\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
  \gantttitle{Year 1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 3}{4}\\
\ganttbar{WP1 Theoretical part}{1}{5} \\
\ganttbar{WP1 Experimental part}{2}{6} \\
\ganttbar{WP2 Theoretical part}{7}{11}\\
\ganttbar{WP2 Experimental part}{8}{12}\\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray,pattern=north east lines}]{WP3 Theoretical part}{6}{12}\\
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=gray,pattern=north east lines}]{WP3 Experimental part}{7}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
```

And the idea is to have WPx labels on the left of the chart, but "Theoretical/experimental part" labels inside the bars. Is it possible to make this with pgfgantt?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use two `\ganttbars`; the second one using the `inline` option. Below, this approach, thorough a command:

```
\Dganttbar{<side text>}{<inline text>}{<start>}{<end>}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newcommand\Dganttbar[4]{%
  \ganttbar{#1}{#3}{#4}\ganttbar[inline,bar label font=\footnotesize]{#2}{#3}{#4}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\Dganttbar{WP1}{Theoretical part}{1}{5} \\
\Dganttbar{WP1}{Experimental part}{2}{6} \\
\Dganttbar{WP2}{Theoretical part}{7}{11}\\
\Dganttbar{WP2}{Experimental part}{8}{12}\\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @pkazmierczak You're welcome! I edited my answer suppressing a superfluous ` \\ ` command.

Comment: That is a nice solution indeed! Nevertheless, unfortunately I'm loosing all my other `ganttbar`-options like `[progress=00, name=test1]` when using it. How can I combine your nice text option AND the original options? It should look like that: `\Dganttbar[progress=00, name=test1]{Text in outer label}{Text in ganttbar}{01.01.2018}{01.02.2018}`.